# Merging recorded times by different timeMeasureEnd blocks into a single histogram

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have multiple timeMeasureEnd blocks as presented in the image below. I intend to build a single histogram with the information recorded by all blocks. Can it be done? Thank you in advance!

[image: Time measure blocks in detail]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options for you, either keep the data in the individual data sets and then save the last entry to the histogram data or clear them and just take entry 0

[image]

Comment: Both worked really well! Thank you!